# How can one sex taking longer to gestate than the other affect a mother biologically?

Tags: science-based, biology

There s an old rumor which says that boys generally spend more time in the womb and take longer to gestate. This has been proven to be untrue, as the time depends more on the child's' growth than gender. In this fictional setting, females spend the traditional 9 months to grow, but boys take slower to develop. They need a n additional 3 months in the womb, and equire more energy resources from the body. This occurs naturally in human development. how could this this have occured in our evolution?

Comment: Avoid using science based as only tag in a question.

Comment: @L.Dutch, Incognito narrowed this temendously.  Would you agree it's enough to reopen it?

Comment: @JBH, I still have the impression that it falls into the class "what are the effects of X on Y?". But I'll let the community decide on that.

Comment: What makes you think that there would be any important biological ramifications? Women are perfectly able to carry 9 month pregnancies, why wouldn't they be able to carry 12 month pregnancies? Seriously, you need to explain your areas of concern.

Comment: This could occur in natural evolution if males are substantially larger than females (or stronger, or smarter). Larger or more advanced organs take longer to develop. Females with shorter pregnancies end up giving birth to smaller or weaker  males, who end up losing the survival and mating competition to males who gestated longer.